# properly format string before loading in openssl

Tags: php

I have a certificate string that is dynamically generated like so. If you look carefully there is a line break \r\n after every 64 characters (I know this to be true because the function I am using to create them includes it). For only the first line the break occurs after the 5 dashes.

**Example 1 - Fails**

```
$string = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFFDCCA/ygAwIBAgIQWh1+7npzhkMdCWe83N5qATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB+ MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEdMBsGA1UEChMUU3ltYW50ZWMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xHzAd BgNVBAsTFlN5bWFudGVjIFRydXN0IE5ldHdvcmsxLzAtBgNVBAMTJlN5bWFudGVj IENsYXNzIDMgU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQSAtIEc0MB4XDTE2MDYwOTAwMDAwMFoX DTE3MDYxMDIzNTk1OVowcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxETAPBgNVBAgMCE5ldyBZb3Jr MREwDwYDVQQHDAhOZXcgWW9yazEXMBUGA1UECgwOSlBNb3JnYW4gQ2hhc2UxCzAJ BgNVBAsMAklCMRcwFQYDVQQDDA4/LmpwbWNoYXNlLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcN AQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKqMdBSgHBZmSlQ1XPhjYr3FHsJFbX1XNt5bAbko F74M3SBxwUfQEi+N6JNFGoMpkRZrLd8DgW8iqmAkt4ZSz4hAiJzDFtV+3UzPnI2O LkArSsg2Anyx1H8NAHwq3OH62Q5Tz7Lu2o09l+s+JFL05PUjlKZioYLNQTDkM7xY xrkFeY/FdqTEYs8a5SUm8cijfwnrZN9tBZ3F1rmgF5UfhRBGw0bOvUsVsixhrXYx Oigy+zLCq0feTnm3YjB5tkHIsropJD7wxEHBQ6RWFNRSqN40+YJ7A1cJiLMDcWBO S2GPwt5TA3vKThGMlXpwQx6s0S7jrEz3mFp8DB6S3hkXJTsCAwEAAaOCAZgwggGU MDkGA1UdEQQyMDCCDj8uanBtY2hhc2UubmV0gg4/LmpwbWNoYXNlLm5ldIIOPy5q cG1jaGFzZS5uZXQwCQYDVR0TBAIwADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwHQYDVR0lBBYw FAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMGEGA1UdIARaMFgwVgYGZ4EMAQICMEwwIwYI KwYBBQUHAgEWF2h0dHBzOi8vZC5zeW1jYi5jb20vY3BzMCUGCCsGAQUFBwICMBkM F2h0dHBzOi8vZC5zeW1jYi5jb20vcnBhMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFF9gz2GQVd+EQxSK YCqy9Xr0QxjvMCsGA1UdHwQkMCIwIKAeoByGGmh0dHA6Ly9zcy5zeW1jYi5jb20v c3MuY3JsMFcGCCsGAQUFBwEBBEswSTAfBggrBgEFBQcwAYYTaHR0cDovL3NzLnN5 bWNkLmNvbTAmBggrBgEFBQcwAoYaaHR0cDovL3NzLnN5bWNiLmNvbS9zcy5jcnQw EwYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAwEB/wQCBQAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAKfIv8hA4PE/ q8594w0pNOzb1VP05Ial/z9Nxa2q0rUuOd1mb0T0FzeW+adUyIDHFVITrmiQvEn3 pXDNqw3iM0lCj14paCHlk+cA8X/cEdq/eMmruI15ee1kuDOtPEotnJ2WmUo9VWQz fukRPA6TxP3k3n9cwn8cWUCoW0SymkDcH+SjTbLBbIxDkOGF0lGRMUWtevXYiHVo 04edymdsseqzmHzs9nRlEfb+EZ060eYdfEG79cK/3mCIVkPlavw7+ykp+j5dQ7LU BZf8TLjdUUHSUmUBlb32WhZShSEvHPcnvmZEPkXH0VBIbtkCQZ1nlIpnY4v0Y3Lx 8Uxg/R7Af7Q= -----END CERTIFICATE-----';
```

For some reason when I try to load this certificate into openssl it complains with the following warning:

```
$pem='';
openssl_x509_export($string, $pem);
```

> Warning: openssl_x509_export(): cannot get cert from parameter 1

**Example 2 - Works**

However, if i load the same certificate from a file or from a string below it works fine.

```
string ='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
```

Is there a way I can make this work with the first string or re-work it in a way to make openssl read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found a solution to my problem

```
$header = array("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- "," -----END CERTIFICATE-----"); //headers to strip
$string = str_replace($header, '', $certdata); //string with stripped headers
$string = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n".str_replace(' ',"\r\n",$string)."\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"; //rebuld string with headers and new lines
```

This works but if there is a more elegant solution I would still be interested in it.